# Why do electronegative heteroatoms increase C=O stretching frequency (bond strength)

Tags: spectroscopy, carbonyl-compounds, ir-spectroscopy

Why does a more electronegative heteroatom (i.e. $\ce{Cl}$ or $\ce{O}$) increase the stretching frequency of a carbonyl?

I'd suspect it's that they donate their lone pairs and we end up with a negative charge on the oxygen in one of our resonance structures which makes the electrostatic attraction between the carbon and oxygen larger?

Comment: Also, inductive effects create a larger dipole in the c=o bond which increases the electrostatic contribution to the bond strength